# How to fix Game freeze when OnTriggerCollider?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have one kinematic object (player) which i move very fast (it's need), also i have another objects(obstacles) - they have collider (trigger), and when collider of player enter obstacle collider and trigger event, game freeze to half or one second.

if i reduce speed, then everything is fine

i've tried make player not kinematic and mark obstacles as not trigger (for use OnCollisionEnter event)

how i move player:

```cs
void FixedUpdate() {
        if (currentWalk != Direction.NONE)
        {
            checkDirection(); // when distance <0.1f stop moving
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, nextPosition, speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);  //speed = 25f;
        }
    }
```

nextPosition = Vector3(0f,0f,7f); // just for example, initially player stand in 0,0,0

```cs
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
    {
        if (collider.tag == "Finish")
        {
            success.SetActive(true); //success - any object which initially
 inactive
        }
    }
```

I expect the game won't be freeze, without reduce speed, because i really don't know, what is problem, there are many game with high speed.

Comment: It's hard to say with what you've posted.  Try opening up the profiler (_Window > Analysis > Profiler_) and checking out the CPU usage during that time.  [Here's a doc on how to do that.](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProfilerCPU.html)

Comment: i looked there, this trouble is only on the phone (Android), on editor everything is fine